# 2 questions about CompareTo() method in C#

Tags: c#, string, compareto

I have 2 questions about the `CompareTo()` method in c#:

1. I read this method compares between the letters in two strings and returns the difference between the Unicode values of the first pair of letters, that aren't the same in the both strings. But when I run it, it always returns -1, 0, or 1. For example:

```
string s1, s2;

s1 = "AARZNML";
s2 = "AARZK";

Console.WriteLine(s1.CompareTo(s2));
```

In the book it was said that the code must return -24, but it returns -1, when I run it.

2. What is `CompareTo()` method supposed to return when I compare a string with uppercase letters and a string with lowercase lowercase. For example I ran this code:

```
string s1, s2;

s1 = "A";
s2 = "a";

Console.WriteLine(s1.CompareTo(s2));
```

and it returned 1, how can it be? Because 'A' is before 'a' in ASCII Table.

Comment: @Selvin I see OP point: A is ascii 65 while a is ascii 97, so A should come before a and so result should be -1 according to docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-7.0

Comment: [order is aAbBcC...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/57YXF6)

Comment: 1.) The docs define the result as smaller, greater or equal 0. It should be -1,0,1 in all implementation(i know off) but isn't guaranteed and one shouldn't program against that detail. You presumably misinterpreted the 24 in your book or it maybe isn't one for c#/net. 2.) Sort Order is Culture dependent. So don't expect a fixed order when you don't specify the culture to be used explicitly.

Comment: "I read this method compares between the letters in two strings and returns the difference between the Unicode values of the first pair of letters" I think you should return your book because it is factually incorrect, and not backed up by the documentation.

Comment: @Charlieface as I found out by accident in globalization-invariant mode it behaves exactly as described (though it returns `-32`, not sure why -24 was expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when I run it, it always returns -1, 0, or 1.

Because the only contract [`string.CompareTo(string? strB)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-7.0#system-string-compareto(system-string)) has is that it:

> ##### Returns
>
> A 32-bit signed integer that indicates whether this instance precedes, follows, or appears in the same position in the sort order as the `strB` parameter.

| Value | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| Less than zero | This instance precedes `strB`. |
| Zero | This instance has the same position in the sort order as `strB`. |
| Greater than zero | This instance follows `strB`. -or- `strB` is null. |

So implementation is free to return any integer matching the rules. It is quite common to implement `IComparable.CompareTo` in a way that it uses only those 3 numbers (-1, 0, 1) as return values but this is not guaranteed in general.

Note that:

> Both overloads of the `CompareTo` method perform **culture-sensitive** and case-sensitive comparison. For code clarity, we recommend that you avoid the `CompareTo` method and call the `Compare` method instead.

I.e. the following:

```
foreach(var s in new []{s1, s2}.Order(StringComparer.CurrentCulture))
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Prints `a` and then `A`, so in default ordering (on my machine with my default culture) `A` follows `a`, so the result is of `ComapareTo` is *Greater than zero*.

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AMgJZQCOA3OunjgM5IA02dCVa6D2AvNgEQBBPu1Y9+AQ2HUMSAJwAKBvgDCAewC2AB3FgApgBVVihAEoT7dADNVe8QGMAFvIBuOlgH1spbFF0B3bABtAF0AbwZmVgBffAB5MAATXTB5AGVgMFIAczUtHWSVCDA9KGBlCAAbYCLdM3RsBtw5RXdzIA)

As experiment you can set globalization-invariant mode (add `<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>` entry to `PropertyGroup` in .csproj) which changes the behaviour - for me result was `-32` and `A` is printed before `a`.

Comment: You might want to add that that to get around the culture-sensitive thing you need to use Compare instead of CompareTo. There one can define the behavior. CompareTo more or less just hides that parameter.

Comment: @Ralf thank you, updated the quote from the docs.