# Can C# CompareTo() and Compare() return integers other than -1 and 1?

Tags: c#

## Can C# CompareTo() and Compare() return integers other than -1 and 1?

I'd like to clarify three matters:

1. Does the "relative" integer returned by the methods include other numbers apart from `-1` and `1`?
2. In C#, which letters come first in the sorting order: UPPER CASE or lower case?
3. Do letters have a fixed integer value in C# by which one could calculate or crosscheck what `CompareTo()` or `Compare()` would return?

My questions are based on the fact that every web site I've been to says both the C# `CompareTo()` and the `Compare()` methods will compare two strings and return values as follows:

1. where `string1` comes *before* `string2`, methods return `-1`;
2. where `string1` comes *after* `string2`, methods return `1`; and,
3. where `string1` and `string2` are identical, methods return `0`.

If I keep only to the examples on the sites, I get the same results with the sites. However, when I use my own strings, with both `CompareTo()` and `Compare()`, I get different numbers: not just `-1` or `1`, as in this example:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("Aloha!", "Hello!"));
Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("Hello!", "Aloha!"));
Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("Hello!", "Hello!"));
```

Console Output

```
-7
7
0
```

Comment: "every web site I've been to" - not including the MS documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=net-8.0 for example.

Comment: FYI, which version of Visual Studio you use is of no relevance for the behavior of the program. It's more about which version of .NET you're running. Also, for the basic behavior, the version is rarely important, neither. :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten you say that, but there were some significant changes to some string sort behaviours between netfx / early .net core, and .net 5 onwards - to move from NLS to ICU rules:  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus

Comment: Yes it definitely can. Check for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000451/2501279) (see the globalization-invariant mode note at the bottom).

Comment: @MarcGravell I'll take your word at the face value (since you've got the tendency to be right). That said, I may stand corrected on the latter of my statements. However, the former, regarding the version of the IDE, I would find surprising if it mattered. (Of course, I can't state that too categorically as there **may** be some edge case proving me wrong. But surprised, I would definitely be.) Thanks for the remark. Appreciate it.

Comment: @KonradViltersten totally agree on the IDE; as for the compare changing: battle scars for me! it changed how routing worked in azure functions with proxies enabled (the route table was sorted by pattern/priority, and some ASCII tokens we were using for placeholders etc: swapped order), and I had to fix it (fortunately the unit tests caught it); I had to manually implement a custom compare to use the old sort order, which as far as I could tell: could not be reproduced without enabling NLS back-compat, and we wanted to avoid the OS tie-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are simply negative, zero, or positive; any values beyond that are incidental. In many cases, the implementation just uses integer subtraction, for example `return x - y;` might be a perfectly compliant implementation. You should not infer any meaning other than that. A string comparer, for example, *could* do this on a character by character basis:

```
(pseudo-code, assumes same length)
for each c1 in s1, c2 in s2 // pairwise
  if (c1 != c2) return c1 - c2
return 0
```

So:

1. yes, but you shouldn't infer anything from the value beyond checking for negative / zero / positive
2. depends on the string comparer
3. depends on the string comparer

Comment: The gist is: you should not check for -1/0/1 but for lessThanZero/zero/greaterThanZero as documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=net-8.0

Comment: Marc Gravell, you clarified the questions. Online tutorials might take a cue and state where returns can be relative.

Answer (score 1):

The compare function returns:
An integer that indicates the lexical relationship between the two comparands.

- Less than zero: The substring in strA precedes the substring in strB in the sort order.
- Zero: The substrings occur in the same position in the sort order, or length is zero.
- Greater than zero: The substring in strA follows the substring in strB in the sort order.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-8.0

Comment: Sorry, Jan-Marten, you explained how `Compare()` works, basically repeating a part of my question, but you didn't address any of the three questions.